# Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 Disable critical battery message

Tags: gnome, battery, notification

I'm using Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 on a laptop with a broken battery.
I can use my laptop always plugged no problem, but I can't get rid of the notification "Critical battery".

I tried to go to dconf editor and change values:

[see screnshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkEa0.png)

I also tried with gconf:

```
gconftool --set /org/mate/power-manager/notify-low-power --type boolean false
gconftool --set /org/mate/power-manager/notify-low-capacity --type boolean false
```

And also to disable all notifications but I can't get rid of this message, which is apping every ~10s. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Is yours a removable battery?

Comment: Unfortunately not :/ No easy fix there

Comment: Why not replace the battery? They can be had inexpensively, even on eBay.